Can we add filters on Global search
On opportunity record, while adding Contact roles (OpportunityContactRole - related list) via 'Add Contact roles' standard button, I have to search from all the Contacts existing in the org. Instead , can we add any filter here so that I can search from list of Contacts of the associated Opportunity's Account and not all the contacts in the org.

This is a standard button and I'm not finding any way to add filter on this button.


I don't think we can add filter on 'Add Contact Roles' button.
